# Iexpress for large files (corrupted Cabinet file)

Tags: iexpress

I wish to combine many installers and make an exe using Iexpress. Total size of installers is 750MB. I tried combine and generated using Iexpress but the created exe file size is only 80MB. And when i double click and attempt to run the exe, its stated that its corrupted cabinet file and cannot be executed. After that i rebuild two exe files by separated installers into two groups and each group file size is around 300++MB. Both exe files are executed successfully. So i suspect that i cannot build all installers into one exe due to its large size. May i ask whether it is correct that iexpress will restrict the exe file size or i am doing something wrong on this?

Answer (score 7):

I think a IExpress package is limited to about the size of a CD-ROM. If you look at the auto-generated DDF file that IExpress generates, one of the directives it gives is:

```
.Set MaxDiskSize=CDROM
```

Probably this means ~650MB.

I tried to find a way to change it, but I don’t see how, sorry.

Comment: Checking the DDF file I see another directive: `.Set MaxCabinetSize=999999999`.

Comment: @JuanFerrer, which OS was this? They may have raised the limit (my answer here is a few years old now, and probably checked in Windows 7).

Comment: Oh, no, the limit is still that. I'm just saying there is another directive, but it seems to be ignored or used for something different. Windows 10 is what I'm using.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see that the directive names were different. Thanks!