# What is the condition for iexpress restart

Tags: iexpress

I use iexpress.exe to quickly create a simple installer based on a batch file. The IExpress Wizards provides the option "Only restart if needed".

But how can I tell from the batch file that a restart is required? I tried using exit code 3016 as in windows updates. But that doesn't work.

BTW: I call the batch file with

```
cmd.exe /c my.bat
```

The contents of my.bat:

```
exit /b 3010
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to get IExpress to recognize the return code. I think you want `3010`, not `3016`, though. Also the command would be:

```
exit 3010
```

[No `/b` – we want to return an exit code from `cmd`, not set `errorlevel`].

But it didn’t work, which makes me wonder if IExpress even bothers to check that.

---

Anyhow, I did a bit of investigation with Process Monitor. Immediately after the *install process* runs, it seems IExpress checks the `PendingFileRenameOperations` registry value to see whether files have been marked for rename (or deletion). If there are any, it determines that a reboot is needed, and takes the action you specified in your SED file (eg prompt the user for a reboot; or just reboot; or nothing).

> In case you’re not familiar with it, the `PendingFileRenameOperations` registry value is a list of files to be moved or deleted on the next system boot.

You can use [Sysinternals MoveFile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb897556.aspx) to simulate one of these scheduled-at-next-startup renames. Add `movefile.exe` to your IExpress archive, and add a line like this in your batch file:

```
movefile.exe -accepteula foo bar
```

The actual filenames aren’t important – just use a file that you know is certain to *not* exist. (As long as you didn’t change directory in the batch file, that’ll still be a file in, eg, `%temp%\IXP000.TMP`.)

Note that you need to be running elevated for that (Run as administrator).

Worked well here. IExpress pops up after each run, prompting the user to reboot.

Comment: Thanks for your investigation. Unfortunateley I finally use 7z to create a SFX installer as I ran into the  [IExpress MaxDiskSize problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045770/iexpress-for-large-files-corrupted-cabinet-file). Anyway I will mark your answer as accepted.